# Laptop keyboard and touchpad not working

Tags: drivers, keyboard, touchpad

My friend just installed Debian on his laptop, a Lenovo Ideapad Slim 3 14. He has Linux version `6.1.0-12-amd64`.

However, his integrated touchpad and keyboard don’t work. The issue happens on both Wayland and Xorg, and in TTY mode. It happens on Ubuntu 23.04 live as well.

Both work in Windows 11, and the keyboard works in GRUB.

An external keyboard connected by USB does work on Linux, though.

First, when looking at the dmesg, we saw these messages:

```
i8042: PNP: PS/2 Controller [PNP0303:KBC0] at 0x60,0x64 irq 1
i8042: PNP: PS/2 appears to have AUX port disabled, if this is incorrect please boot with i8042.nopnp
```

So we added the `i8042.nopnp` option to the kernel parameters. When rebooting, the messages were gone, and this got written to the dmesg:

```
input: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard as /devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input0
```

But the keyboard still didn’t work.

We tried adding each of the following kernel parameters, none changed anything:

- `i8042.dumbkbd=1`
- `i8042.direct`
- `i8042.dritek=1`
- `pci.norcs`

Here is the keyboard’s entry in `/proc/bus/input/devices`:

```
I: Bus=0011 Vendor=0001 Product=0002 Version=ab00
N: Name="AT Raw Set 2 keyboard"
P: Phys=isa0060/serio0/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input0
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=sysrq kbd event0
B: PROP=0
B: EV=100013
B: KEY=402000000 3803078f800d001 feffffdfffefffff fffffffffffffffe
B: MSC=10
```

We can see the keyboard’s device file is `/dev/input/event0`. He tried to `cat` the file and use his keyboard, which prints nothing to the terminal. It does print something on my laptop.

`i8042` doesn’t appear in `lsmod`. `modprobe i8042` prints nothing and doesn’t solve the issue.

Do you have any idea to further investigate the issue?

[dmesg](https://dpaste.com/746MNMYPN)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is actually a known issue about the Linux kernel, [here is the ticket](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=217873).